# wordpress profile builder not redirecting properly after registration

Tags: wordpress, redirect, user-profile

I am using "profile builder pro" plugin of wordpress in wordpress website and it works well except for "redirection after successfull registration" as it is redirecting to the same page.
here is a live link of it

```
http://www.selfmadesounds.com/dev3/register
```

Login redirection and register redirection i have set from backend and it is working for login but not for registration.

Any help will be pretty much accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the pro version but had the same problem, i fixed it by hardcoding the redirect link.

Go to the page "wp-content/plugins/profile-builder/front-end/wppb.register.php"

Move to line 1026 and add the following:

```
$redirectLink = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/REDIRECT-PAGE';
```

Just simply overwrite the redirectLink before it go's and redirect.

Hope it helps

Comment: This could work for a while, but probably only til next update of Profile Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't edit plugin files directly! Really bad practice.

You can solve this in a couple of ways, one way is to check if logged in and on a specific page then redirect to another page. There are nicer ways then hardcoding the urls and id, but this is better then editing plugin files directly.

Put this in your functions.php, change url and id to the one you need:

```
function isLoginPage() {
    global $post;
    return is_object($post) && (int) $post->ID === 1;
}

add_action('wp', 'redirectFromLoginpage');

function redirectFromLoginpage() {
    if (isLoginPage()) {
        global $wppb_login;

        if (is_user_logged_in() || isset($wppb_login->ID)) {  // Already logged in 
            wp_redirect(site_url() . '/redirect-to-this-url/');
            die;
        } 
    }
}
```